# My data has two headers (variable type and grouping factor). How can I split the header and turn the grouping factor into a column?

Tags: r

My csv file has two headers, like this:

```
 Run #1,Run #1,Run #2,Run #2 
 Angle,Light,Angle,Light 
 a,b,c,d    
 e,f,g,h
```

The first header gives the measurement number, the second the type of measurement. I would like my data to look like this:

```
Run Angle Light
1    a      b
1    e      f
2    c      d
2    g      h
```

To read the table into R, I had to read in the headers separately using scan and then merge them into one a single header:

```
header <- scan(file, nlines = 1, sep=",",what = character())
header2 <- scan(file, skip = 1, nlines = 1, sep = ",", what = character())

df<- read.table(file, sep=",", header=F, skip=2)
names(df) <- paste(header, header2, sep = "_")
```

So I ended up with this:

```
structure(list(`Run #1_Angle` = c(0, 0.01, 0.02, 0.03), `Run #1_Light` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), `Run #2_Angle` = c(NA, 0, 0, 0), 
    `Run #2_Light` = c(NA, NA, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 
4L), class = "data.frame")
```

I assumed that I would have to gather, then spread:

```
df_fix<-df %>%
  gather()%>%
  separate(key, into = c('run', 'variable'), sep = "_") %>% 
  mutate(variable=as.factor(variable)) %>% 
  mutate(run=as.factor(run)) %>% 
  group_by(run) %>% 
  spread(variable, value)
```

Which gives me this error:

```
Error: Each row of output must be identified by a unique combination of keys. Keys are shared for 526500 rows.
```

526500 rows is my entire dataset, so I'm not quite sure what this means and how to avoid it?
Alternatively, is there a different way of keeping part of the header and transforming the other part into a column?

Comment: Usually when I get data like this, I'll read the file in twice (or if it's large, read it as lines, then parse it separately): once to get just the header rows, then once skipping all but the last header. Reshape both, then use those headers to join. The error is probably because you need some sort of identifier, like a row number

Comment: Thank you! That sounds like another good method, but akrun's answer worked perfectly. I looked at the other question earlier but there are some differences to my problem, and I could not figure out a way to make the solution work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `gather/spread`, we may use `pivot_longer` to convert the 'wide' format to 'long' format

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>% 
   pivot_longer(cols = everything(), names_to = c("Run", ".value"), 
      names_pattern = ".*\\s+#(\\d+)_(\\w+)", values_drop_na = TRUE)
# A tibble: 7 × 3
  Run   Angle Light
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 1      0        0
2 1      0.01     0
3 2      0       NA
4 1      0.02     0
5 2      0        0
6 1      0.03     0
7 2      0        0
```